# Какую лучше сделать оплату на сайте?

Tags: банковские-карты

Всем привет, планирую добавить на свой портал виртуальную валюту, что-то похожее на голоса вконтакте. и соответственно ее нужно покупать за деньги, кроме того должна быть возможность вывести назад. Как удобней всего организовать оплату? сложность кода и настройка не имеет значения, главное безопасность и удобство!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если главное действительно безопасность и удобство , я бы поставил Paypal + Stripe.
Google/Facebook/Телефон для аутентификации.
Опять таки , много вопросов по типу: контингент , страна , размеры платежей.

P.S. Пока у Вас не всё готово, имеет смысл запустить без аутентификации.